# Creating a "pinhole" small enough to allow only one molecule to pass through

Tags: mechanical-engineering, gas, biomechanics

Consider a "cartridge" of sorts. Is it possible to construct a "pinhole" in the cartridge such that only one molecule will pass through at a time? If so, what sort of equipment would I need to construct such a pinhole, or what sort of company would I need to contact? (The cheaper the method, the better.)

For reference, the molecules in question are [deoxribonucleotides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deoxyribonucleotide), which are about 13 angstroms or 1.3 nanometers in diameter. The molecules would I believe be in the state of a gas.

Comment: For those of us not familiar with DNA analysis, you might post the physical dimensions of these four famous molecules. But in any case, what would you do with a single molecule floating in the exterior gas?

Comment: Very tiny holes can be "drilled" into metal foils using electron beam lithography. It will not be cheap though !

Comment: @CarlWitthoft the question has been updated with that information, I'm sorry I couldn't provide it sooner.

Comment: im sure the answer is no, but try physics.stackexchange.com